# Image empty while updating image after succesful upload via Kartik FileInput Yii2 widget with Ajax method

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I have a form to update my news post which have title, content and image upload button at the same page. The image uploader use Kartik FileINput widget for Yii2 applying Ajax method.

This is my actionUpload that processed the AJAX uploading

```
public function actionUpload($id)
{
$model = $this->findModel($id);
$currentImage=$model->image;
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) 
    {
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

            $image = $model->uploadImage();
            if($image===false)
                             {
                                  //echo "image instance is empty";
                                  $model->image = $currentImage; 
                            }

            if ($model->validate() && $model->save()) 
             {
                if($image !== false)
                    {
                  $model->image = $image->basename.'.'.$image->extension;
                $image->saveAs('uploads/batam/'.$model->image);
                $model->save(false);
                return \yii\helpers\Json::encode(array("image" => $model->image,
                    ));
                    }
             }
             else
                {echo "validation failed";}
    }
}
```

This is my widget file upload filed in my form (note : it's inside the active form)

```
echo FileInput::widget([
    'name' => 'image',
    'options'=>[
        'multiple'=>false
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [

         'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['news/upload','id'=>$id]),
         'uploadExtraData' => [
            'id'=>$id,
        ],
        'initialPreview'=>[
          Yii::getAlias('@web').'/uploads/batam'.$model->image
        ],
        'initialPreviewAsData'=>true,
        'overwriteInitial'=>false,
        'maxFileSize'=>2800
    ]
]);
```

this is my model rule and uploadImage method

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title', 'content'], 'required'],
            [['content'], 'string'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['image'], 'file','skipOnEmpty'=>true, 'extensions'=>'jpg,png,jpeg'],
            [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    public function uploadImage() {
        $image = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('image');
        if (empty($image)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $image;
    }
```

I have 2 issues here that needs help :
 1. The validation rules won't work. I can upload any file with any extension and it's succesfully uploaded and updated in the database
 2. The image upload was contained within the active form, so after a successful upload using AJAX, when I press 'update' button, the image won't display. The `image` field is treated as empty, so the `update` button behave as if I updated an empty image. In my database the image path of the AJAX-uploaded file of the respected `news-id` has been succesfully stored and the file is uploaded.
 How to solve this? Actually I don't mind if the upload method didn't use AJAX but just the ordinary, single form submit method with `post`, thus omitting the `upload` ajax button, but according to Kartik documentary, if I want to use the widget that display the previously stored image, it needs Ajax.

I had looked around some similar question in StackOverflow etc but all of them had the problem with empty image instance in the Ajax call method ( well, I previously faced the same problem, but i had apply the Formdata on my ajax after I researched), while I don't have the problem with the empty instance on ajax call, but empty instance on the normal form submit.

This is my actionUpdate

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
$image= UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('image');

 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() ){
var_dump($image);exit();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,

            ]);
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the reason why the validators are not working is because you are NOT creating the file input widget from the model, you must do it this way in order for your rules in the class model to work:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
]);
```

Then I don't know how the structure of your database, but my advice for how to handle image uploads. Is, first, to create a public variable inside the class separated from the image field of the database, this public image variable will be the one that will instanciate the widget on the form and also the one with the rules. This way, when you post your form, the image field from the database will not be overwrited.

So, then when you upload using ajax, you will send the id of the object too, and in the upload function once everything is set, you will store the path, or the image, or whatever in the image field of the database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If I echo the widget as what you said it'll work but it doesn't provide an initial preview of the stored image. I need to do it as stated above  according to the Kartik documentation. But I also changed the first line of my code to `echo $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::widget([
    'model'=>$model,` and everything else is the same, but I got an `IE-10 browser error` that my browser doesn't support file preview multiple file upload. I;m using the latest chrome btw and tried also in latest opera but still got the same error

Comment: As for the structure, I don't have separate `image` table but rather I make the `news` table have `image` column that store the uploaded image path. Can you please elaborate and provide a simple example on what you said : `to create a public variable inside the class separated from the image field of the database, this public image variable will be the one that will instanciate the widget on the form ` ? Thanks @Josep Vidal

Comment: @codejunkie it wil not provide an initial image because the value of model image is empty, so when it renders the component there are no image, in order to show a preview image you could load the default image in the controller before the render. Inside the controller that renders the form, after you load the model class you could do something like $model->image = "default-path-to-image.jpg".  You could create a image input without model, but then, the rules inside the model will not aply to the input form.

Comment: Yes @codejunkie, check this model from one of my repos: https://github.com/jvidalv/dishora/blob/master/models/Empresa.php , look at the public variable with the name of $foto, it is not a row in the database, I only use it to render the form and retrieve the image.